# Lognormal distributed variable, find likelihood

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Using scipy, I'd like to get a measure of how likely it is that a random variable was generated by my log-normal distribution.

To do this I've considered looking at how far it is from the maximum of the PDF.

My approach so far is this: If the variable is `r = 1.5`, and the distribution σ=0.5, find the value from the PDF, `lognorm.pdf(r, 0.5, loc=0)`. Given the result, (`0.38286..`), I would then like to look up what area of the PDF is below `0.38286..`.

How can this last step be implemented? Is this even the right way to approach this problem?

To give a more general example of the problem. Say someone tells me they have 126 followers on twitter. I know that Twitter followers are a log-normal distribution, and I have the PDF of that distribution. Given that distribution do I determine how believable this number of followers is?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870982/how-do-i-get-a-lognormal-distribution-in-python-with-mu-and-sigma)? (It might help.)

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand what that question is about. I have no problem getting an accurate result from a PDF, but want to ask what fraction of the PDF would get that value or lower.

Comment: What you are looking for is precisely the CDF, see my answer. :) (To be honest I didn't really understand that question either, but it did help!)

Answer (score 2):

The area under the PDF is the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) (which is conveniently a method in [lognorm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html)):

```
lognorm.cdf(r, 0.5, loc=0)
```

.

One thing you can use this to calculate is the Folded Cumulative Distribution (mentioned [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html)), also known as a "mountain plot":

```
FCD = 0.5 - abs(lognorm.cdf(r, 0.5, loc=0) - 0.5)
```

Comment: I know about the CDF, but it doesn't solve my problem. Say the PDF of r=1.5 is ~0.38, the CDF is ~0.79. The PDF of r=0.405 is also ~0.38, but the CDF is ~0.03. I want a distribution that gives both low and high outliers the same value.

Comment: @lyschoening could you take `abs(CDF-0.5)`?

Comment: I could take the `[CDF at the low side] + (1 - [CDF at the high side])`, so `0.03 + (1-0.79) = 0.24` in this example.

Comment: @lyschoening Neither of these things have the *meaning* of likelihood "a random variable was generated by my log-normal distribution". To be honest, I don't think there is an answer to that particular question (besides 0, which presumably you wouldn't consider an answer).

Comment: I feared something like that. I guess I have to rephrase the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @lyschoening The answer will almost surely be 0! :)

Comment: I had another look at your `abs(CDF-0.5)` suggestion. I was too quick to discard it. This here does what I want: `1-abs(cdf(r)-0.5)*2`

Comment: @lyschoening I was going to suggest just that! Is this the Folded cumulative Distribution, I'll update my answer to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

same result as hayden's

For statistical tests with an asymmetric distribution, we get the pvalue by taking the minimum of the two tail probabilities

```
>>> r = 1.5
>>> 0.5 - abs(lognorm.cdf(r, 0.5, loc=0) - 0.5) 
0.20870287338447135
>>> min((lognorm.cdf(r, 0.5), lognorm.sf(r, 0.5)))
0.20870287338447135
```

This is usually doubled to get the two-sided p-value, but there are some recent papers that suggest alternatives to the doubling.