# Skewing Lognormal Distribution with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a way to make random draws from a lognormal distribution with a skewed shape parameter?

There are a few questions currently leaving something to be desired on the same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747761/scipy-lognormal-distribution-parameters?lq=1) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870982/how-do-i-get-a-lognormal-distribution-in-python-with-mu-and-sigma).

I'm currently using `scipy.stats.lognorm`. This accepts shape, scale, and location. So, location is the mean (expeceted value), scale is the standard deviation (or spread of the dist), and shape is the skew (?).

How is the skew, typically γ, incorporated into this distribution? Now I can currently only get results with
`s=.998` and `lognorm(s)`, but `s` is restricted to be in `(-1,1)`, when my skew parameter is -2.33.

Comment: The docs list an explicit formula, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html. what is your question again?

Comment: All it says is it requires `s` and gives an example for `s=.954`. What is the `s`, and what are the restrictions on it? For my data I have a skew number of -2.33.

Comment: I want to draw random variables from a lognormal distribution with skew λ, mean μ, and standard deviation σ.