# SciPy stats lognormal distribution obtain pdf with given lognormal distribution mean and lognormal distribution geometric standard deviation

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I am working with droplets distribution, for purpose of my work I would like to create droplet distribution plot. In this case I need `lognorm.pdf` for `scipy`. Unfortunately `scipy` build function `lognorm.pdf` has an equation like this:

`lognorm.pdf(x, s) =   1 / (s*x*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2*(log(x)/s)**2)`

For my case I want to use a formula form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution):

`pdf =  1 / (s*x*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-1/2*((log(x)-mu)/s)**2)`

The best equation would be like this:

`(np.exp(-(np.log10(x) - np.log10(mu))**2 / (2 * np.log10(s)**2))  / ( np.log10(s) * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))*N`

I do have a code which follows the lest equation, but I just wonder if there is any way of doing this with `scipy` or any other python library?

Comment: You have to calculate appropriate parameters for the `scipy.lognorm` class from the mean and standard deviation. See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73567355/10020283).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, if `x` is not too memory consuming:

```
tempX = x / np.exp(mu)
distr = lognorm.pdf(tempX, s)
```

or even define your own function:

```
def lognormMu(x, mu, s):
    tempX = x / np.exp(mu)
    return lognorm.pdf(tempX, s)
```

**#EDIT**

also, [lognorm docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) state explicitly that

> The probability density above is defined in the “standardized” form.
> To shift and/or scale the distribution use the loc and scale
> parameters. Specifically, `lognorm.pdf(x, s, loc, scale)` is identically
> equivalent to `lognorm.pdf(y, s) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.

So it seems that it should be called as

```
distr = lognorm.pdf(x, s, mu)
```

to obtain a desired effect.